# Запрет правого клика блокирует всплывающую картинку в опере

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Всем привет. На сайте добавил скрипт для запрета клика правой кнопкой мыши. В хроме, мозиле, эксплоре все четко, а вот в опере правый клик-то блокируется, но это влияет на всплывающую картинку, реализованную с помощью lightbox fancybox, причем, если кликнуть на превью по бокам, то всплывающая картинка появляется, а если нажать на превью по центру, то нет - отчего так?
вот такой скрипт

```js
<!--
var message = "";

function clickIE() {
  if (document.all) {
    (message);
    return false;
  }
}

function clickNS(e) {
  if (document.layers || (document.getElementById && !document.all)) {
    if (e.which == 2) {
      (message);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
if (document.layers) {
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
  document.onmousedown = clickNS;
} else {
  document.onmouseup = clickNS;
  document.oncontextmenu = clickIE;
}
document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false")
  -- >
```

или такой

```js
<!--
///////////////////////////////////
function clickIE4() {
  if (event.button == 2) {
    return false;
  }
}

function clickNS4(e) {
  if (document.layers || document.getElementById && !document.all) {
    if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
if (document.layers) {
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
  document.onmousedown = clickNS4;
} else if (document.all && !document.getElementById) {
  document.onmousedown = clickIE4;
}
document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false")
  // -->
```

Comment: Этот код ужасно древний... К тому же, считает Хром IE. Лучше переписать или поискать поновее.